# How to catch Device Provisioning Event with Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-suite

I'm trying to implement a list of events with Azure IoT Suite:

- My device connects to the IoT Hub the first time with the **device provisioning service**;
- The device provisioning registers correctly the device and set the device twin;
- An **Azure Logic App** *catchs* this event and starts an Azure Function with a code C# to communicate *cloud-to-device* to this new device. (I would like to set some new parameters).

Is it possible the point number 3? I'm looking to the actions of the Azure Logic App but I don't find anything.
Otherwise, anyone known other alternatives?

Thanks a lot for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Event Grid for this:

1. IoT Hub emits [Device Created events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-event-grid) (plus other events) and sends them to Event Grid
2. [Logic App is triggered](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ukhybridcloud/2018/08/10/building-an-azure-event-grid-app-part-2-adding-a-logic-app-subscriber-to-the-event-grid-topic/) by new events from the Grid.
3. Your Logic App is doing your custom magic :)

If your logic app is doing nothing else apart from invoking the Function, your Function could also directly being invoked by the Event Grid.